# Retrieve AWS EC2s CPUUtilization using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, javafx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to get all the average CPU usage for EC2s in a specific region. I tried the following:

- Request one instance statistics per request, which works but very slow.
- I tried to remove the dimensions from the request but I got an empty response, although cli returns all instances available ([Statistics for up to 35 instances over a span of 24 hours](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html)).
- I tried set 10 dimensions per request but I got this Exception:

  ```
  2016-01-24 23:13:30.925 java[20057:31669898] GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT_EXT java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested texture dimensions (62206x154) require dimensions (0x154) that exceed maximum texture size (16384)
   at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2RTTexture.create(ES2RTTexture.java:220)
   at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2ResourceFactory.createRTTexture(ES2ResourceFactory.java:158)
   at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.createGraphics(ES2SwapChain.java:210)
   at com.sun.prism.es2.ES2SwapChain.createGraphics(ES2SwapChain.java:40)
   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:87)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
   at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ```

code:

```
 private List<Datapoint> monitorInstance(AmazonCloudWatchClient cloudWatchClient, List<Dimension> dimensions) {
     List<Datapoint> datapoints = new ArrayList<>();
     try {
         int dimensionsLastIndex = 0;
         for (int dimensionsIndex = 0; dimensionsIndex < dimensions.size(); dimensionsIndex = dimensionsLastIndex + 1) {
             dimensionsLastIndex = (dimensionsIndex + 10) <= dimensions.size() ? dimensionsIndex + 9 : dimensions.size() - 1;

             long offsetInMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
             GetMetricStatisticsRequest request = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
                     .withStartTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() - offsetInMilliseconds))
                     .withNamespace("AWS/EC2")
                     .withPeriod(60 * 60)
                     .withDimensions(dimensions.subList(dimensionsIndex, dimensionsLastIndex))
                     .withMetricName("CPUUtilization")
                     .withStatistics("Average")
                     .withEndTime(new Date());
             GetMetricStatisticsResult getMetricStatisticsResult = cloudWatchClient.getMetricStatistics(request);

             datapoints.addAll(getMetricStatisticsResult.getDatapoints());
         }
         return datapoints;
     } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
         error(e.getMessage(), stackTraceToString(e));

     }
     return new ArrayList<>();
 }
```

Although I want to fix this Exception, I wonder if there is a simple way to get the stats for all instances in one request.